# Show that a random variable is distributed as a Geometric rv

Tags: self-study, distributions, combinatorics, geometric-distribution

I am working on an assignment: I have a line of numbers that is divided in intervals of fixed length, so for example: [0,c), [c,2c), [2c,3c), etc.

Each interval is numbered 1,2,3 etc. X is an exponential random variable, and N is the interval in which X falls, so: $(N − 1)c ≤ X < N c$.

Now I need to show that N is a Geometric random variable, and give the value c so N is $Geo(0.5)$ distributed.

I am absolutely clueless on how to proceed, I know that the PDF for a geometric distribution is $F(x)=(1-p)^{x-1}p$, but can't think of a way to subtract this from this problem.

Comment: Have you tried _calculating_ the probabilities $P\{0 \leq X < c\},P\{c \leq X < 2c\}, P\{2c \leq X < 3c\}, \cdots$? If you do so, you might see a pattern....

Comment: Hint: The probability _mass_ function (or PMF) of a geometric random variable $N$ is $$p_N(x) = P\{N = x\} = q^{x-1}(1-q), x = 1,2,3,\ldots$$ and not what you have written in your question. Now apply my previous suggestion of calculating $P\{N = 1\} = P\{0 \leq X < x\}$ etc

Comment: Since this is an assignment, I have added the `self-study` tag to your question.